# Django - Serialize response from another server

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF to make a GET request to another server and return this reponse to the client.

What I want to know is how do I get only selected fields from that other server's response to return to my client.

What I have is a response like this:

```
{
"plans": [
  {
"setup_fee": 500,
"amount": 990,
"code": "plano01",
}
{
"setup_fee:...
"code": "plano02",
}...
```

An array with many objects. And I want to give to the client something like this:

```
{
    "plans": [
      {
    "code": "plano01",
    }
    {"code": "plano02"...
```

Only the **code** field.

Whats the best way to do this with Django/DRF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much point in using DRF here. You're getting a response in JSON format, you just need to parse it to a dict, extract the elements you want, and return it back as JSON again; DRF would be overkill.  The view can simply be:

```
def get_plan_codes(request):
    data = requests.get('external_api...').json()
    codes = [{'code': plan['code']} for plan in data['plans']]
    data['plans'] = codes
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: I'm using DRF because I have to use some of the informations that the client sends and also to avoid putting sensitive http header information on the client side. But your answer was very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would use DRF for this personally, although you could.

I think this could be done in a fairly straight foward way using just requests and django itself.

Something like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse

import json
import requests


def plans(request):
    response = requests.get("my url for the request")
    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_content = json.loads(response.content)
        # json_content is a python dictionary, so you can just postprocess the way you want it here
        return JsonResponse(json_content)
    else:
        return #You will want to return an HttpResponse with the appropriate status code, see the docs below on that
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code
```

Comment: This is the thing, I am using requests inside of a DRF request. Because I have to use some of the client's infomation but also information from another API.